# Spring aop with struts2

Tags: java, spring, struts2, aop

I am new to Spring aop and I decided to use aop to track my Struts2 Action class execution time. I have done the following things. But while running the application **setter method of the action class is not called**.
Here is my code.
xml configuration:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<bean id="myAspect" class="abc.xyz.ActionClassAspect"/>
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="actionClassPointcut" expression="execution(public * abc.xyz.action.*.*(..))
        and !execution(public * abc.xyz.action.*Action.get*(..))
        and !execution(public * abc.xyz.action.*Action.set*(..))"/>
    <aop:around pointcut-ref="actionClassPointcut" method="doActionClassProfilling"/>
</aop:config>
```

Aspect:

```
public Object doActionClassProfilling(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Object returnValue = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs());
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(proceedingJoinPoint.getClass()+" TIME: "+(end-start));
    return returnValue;
}
```

Action Class:

```
 private String userID, password;
 @Override
 public String execute() throws Exception {
     try {
         LoginService loginService = LoginService.getInstance();;
         UserProfile userProfile = loginService.validateUser(userID, password);
         Map<String, Object> sessionMap =  ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
         sessionMap.put("USER_PROFILE", userProfile);
         return SUCCESS;
     } catch(Exception e) {
         return ERROR;
     }
 }
 public String getUserID() {
     return userID;
 }
 public void setUserID(String userID) {
     this.userID = userID;
 }
 public String getPassword() {
     return password;
 }
 public void setPassword(String password) {
     this.password = password;
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you just want track execution time, using Struts2 interceptor would be easier

Comment: Not just want to track execution time of action class. I want to track entire transaction. ie. From action class number of services called and each number of DAOs called from that service and execution time of those layers.

Comment: I want this as a separate module. Coz I will remove this module at production time.

Comment: If I use Struts2 Interceptor, at production time I need to rewrite my code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this kind of issue and [This](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-proxying) helped me.
I forced spring AOP to used CGLIB proxy, being aware of the new problems this could create. Now I can advice my struts2 actions!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this works for me as well, by changing the default JDK dynamic proxies into CGLIB with this line in XML:
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>

See section "8.6 Proxying mechanisms" from this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30068987)